# Warning with Nuxt plugins declaration $ vue prefix

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

### I am having an issue with Nuxt plugins:
"nuxt": "^3.4.2",
"vue": "^3.2.47"

plugins.vue

```
import slugify  from 'slugify'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      slugifier: (value) => slugify(value).toLowerCase(),
    }
  }
})
```

---

Index.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  async setup() {
    const { $slugifier } = useNuxtApp()
    return {
      $slugifier
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[Vue warn]: setup() return property "$slugifier" should not start with "$" or "_" which are reserved prefixes for Vue internals.

Is Nuxt using a wording forbidden by VUE ? Or I missed something ?

Thank you for any help

I try to use a plugin tool in my vue following documentation https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins and got a warning.

Comment: The following code in `index.vue` page should work: `<script setup>
  const { $slugifier } = useNuxtApp()
  // ...
</script>`

Comment: Yes it works, but last build has generated a warning about using $ or _ before a constant...